# How to implement google drive in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Can't Im element google drive in iOS it shows an error

> the operation couldn’t be completed (com.google.GIDSignin error - 4.)

under

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error
```

I added below code to to back up something in google drive from textField

```
GIDSignIn* signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly, nil];
[signIn signInSilently];

// Add the sign-in button.
self.signInButton = [[GIDSignInButton alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:self.signInButton];

// Create a UITextView to display output.
self.output = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.output.editable = false;
self.output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0);
self.output.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.output.hidden = true;
[self.view addSubview:self.output];

// Initialize the service object.
self.service = [[GTLRDriveService alloc] init];
```

Comment: It happens if the user has never signed in before with the given scopes, or if they have since signed out. To resolve it, check auth before sign in.

Comment: did the solution worked out for you? @anupan

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there are no auth tokens in the keychain, i.e., "User is not authorized".

To check if the user is authorized, use this piece of code:

```
func checkIfUserIsAuthorized() {
    if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
        // User authorized before
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    } else {
        // User not authorized open sign in screen

    }
}
```